# Is there a way to programmatically get all IgniteQueue & IgniteCache proxies for the caches & queues created on the whole ignite cluster?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am currently running ignite 2.5 & wondering if there is a way to programmatically get all IgniteQueue & IgniteCache proxies for the caches & queues created on the whole ignite cluster (or their configurations, for caches i think i can get that from IgniteConfiguration if its a configured one or from IgniteCache proxy, can queues be configured aswell? also how do i get their configuration).

I see for example this one, Ignite#cacheNames() which i think will returns all cache names including the ones internally created for the queue? I am going to try it but want to make sure i don't do/use something based not documented/intended for the purpose.

The intention is to recreate the queues/caches programmatically if they are no longer present in the cluster.

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

Thanks @alex-k for confirming there is no public API for queues like caches to get the configuration..it would be nice to have had this support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ignite.cacheNames() top get cache names, and Ignite.configuration().getCacheConfiguration() to get the configs.

There are no public APIs to get all queue names.

Comment: Thanks @Alex-K, that's what i was thinking earlier when i mentioned cacheNames() but was not sure if it will or supposed to return the internal cache that is used to support queue aswell. Thanks also for confirming that there is no public API for queue :-(